# ArgumentException on Regex creation

Tags: c#, .net, regex, exception

I have a strange behavior with creation of following regex:

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( "^\\)$" );
```

Sometimes I got ArgumentException, but it occurs very rarely, and I cannot explain why. 
Application is running at .net 4.0 with target x86.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Does the exception provide any further details?  It should have a `Message` property and possibly an inner exception.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the pattern. Assuming what you're looking to match is just the string `")"`. It might be easier to read like this: `new Regex(@"^\)$");`. For an intermittent error like this, I'd be looking for another cause. What information does the exception contain?

Comment: If you are just looking to match a single right bracket, why the regex, when `s == ")"` would do the trick?

Comment: because in my code regex expression builds automatically, and looking for ")" is a partial case..

Comment: @Yuriy Can you show us some of the surrounding code that builds these regexes?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it now, and I'll post all message from exception immediately I get it..

Comment: The messages in the argument exceptions generated by the Regex constructor are pretty good and should tell you exactly what's wrong. e.g. `"parsing "^)$" - Too many )'s"`. They show you the exact pattern and what's wrong with it. I'm betting that somehow your regex generating code is coming up with something other than the `@"^\)$"` you think it is.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The exception message is `Failed to compare two elements in the array`. The same code works on my co-workers machines, so it is likely a development environment problem.